# Find pages with facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to Create or Make an FQL where search using 1 word can find facebook pages.

example:

Search> 
"Soda Stereo" 
Result: 
.... 
.. 
Soda Stereo Fan page

Is  posble create  this with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
/search?q={your_search_string}&type=page&access_token={app_access_token}
```

endpoint for that (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#search), where `{your_search_string}` needs to be replaces with the actual search string (url encoded), and `{app_access_token}` with an actual app access token.

You don't need FQL to do that at all.